# CSS: Child combinator selector & :first-child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a `div` with some other `div`s, some paragraphs and some images in it. It basically looks like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>
        This image is inside a div.
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" alt="" />
    </div>
    <p>
        And this inside a paragraph.
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" alt="" />
    </p>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" alt="" />
</div>
```

Now I only want to select the images that aren't nested inside another `div` or `p`. I am doing this using the child combinator selector:

```
#parent > img {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This works, but now I only want to select the first, non-nested image. I tried it like this, but without any result:

```
#parent > img:first-child {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vF2DU/

How do I do it? Is there a way without adding a class or id like `#first`?

Comment: first-child only works if it is the directly the first child of the parent - so in the case above the div is the first child, also careful when using the `>` as this will only get direct descendants of the parent too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `first-of-type` or the `nth-of-type` selectors.

In this case, `first-of-type` is probably more relevant, but I'll show you the syntax for both below:

---

**About first-of-type:**

> "The :first-of-type selector matches every element that is the first
>   child, of a particular type, of its parent."

**first-of-type example:**

```
#parent > img:first-of-type {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vF2DU/4/) for `first-of-type` in regard to your use case.

---

**About nth-of-type:**

> "The :nth-of-type(n) selector matches every element that is the nth
>   child, of a particular type, of its parent.
>   n can be a number, a keyword, or a formula."

**nth-of-type example:**

```
#parent > img:nth-of-type(1) {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vF2DU/5/) for `nth-of-type` in regard to your use case.

---

**Support:**

Both are supported in all major browsers - Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Internet Explorer (IE9 and above). If you're interested in getting them to work perfectly in IE8 and before, check out [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).

Comment: @Spudley Yup, defo better in this case

Comment: Wow thank you! I didn't even know about these selectors - even the browser support is good, that is one of these "wow moments" for me ;-)

Answer (score 5):

`:first-child` means **first-child**, not first encountered element of a type. What you need is `:first-of-type` selector. [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vF2DU/3/)